# How to add quotation mark in each value in tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple like below:

```
my_tuple = (11, 12, 15)
```

And I need to have quotation marks in each value in the tuple:

```
my_tuple = ('11', '12', '13')
```

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: `my_tuple =tuple(str(x) for x in my_tuple)` or `my_tuple=tuple(map(str,my_tuple))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) to convert each number to a string:

```
my_tuple = (11, 12, 15)
my_tuple = tuple(str(x) for x in my_tuple)
print(my_tuple)
# ('11', '12', '15')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map:

```py
my_tuple = (11, 12, 15)
tuple(map(str, my_tuple))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_tuple = (11, 12, 15)

temp = []
for item in my_tuple:
    temp.append(str(item))
    
my_tuple = tuple(temp)
```